# How to update secrets in jenkins by script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to update/add a secret in the Jenkins by a pipeline script?
To give an example, pipeline A when executed produces a secret file that needs to be used by pipeline B in its future triggers. How can I achieve this?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

In the pipeline A you can mask the secret file and assign as a parameter with the given file path location. And in the pipeline A, pass the parameter when trigger the pipeline B job.

```
  stage('Tigger pipeline B') {
        script {
           build(job: "<Job Name>",
               parameters:
                  [string(name: 'FILE_NAME', value: "${params.FILE_NAME}")])
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pipeline A doesn't trigger pipeline B. They are independent. I meant to ask how can pipeline A update a credential that pipeline B can use.